# Get child elements from a parent but not first and last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how could I write a jQuery selector that get all children from a parent element except first and last child?

Example of my current HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>first child( i don't want to get)</div>
    <div>another child</div>
    <div>another child</div>
    <div>another child</div>
    (...)
    <div>another child</div>
    <div>another child</div>
    <div>last child (i dont want to get neither)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to spell check your questions so they look more professional and not like you are a slacker who doesn't care.

Comment: DVK, I'm sorry, but I don't speak english as first language, I will try to be more carefull.

Comment: most modern web browsers have built-in spell checkers. I never pick on people's English, only on really obvious typos (as non-English-native-speaker, it's very easy for me to know which one's which :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#parent > div:not(:first, :last)');
```

Comment: +1.  I hate your clean solution, yet I find myself strangely attracted to it.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong, but using this selector my script is getting last child.

Comment: @treeface, I found what I did wrong and thanks to show me this tool I loved it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#parent div').not(':first').not(':last')
```

Or

```
$('#parent').children().not(':first').not(':last')
```

Here `not` method will filter out first and last elements from the selector.

**More Information:**

- http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent').children(':not(:first):not(:last)')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent').children().not(':first').not(':last')
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#parent > div:not(:first, :last)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(
            function()
            {
                var a = $("div#parent *:not(:first-child)").not(":last-child");
                alert(a.length);
            }
)
```